# How to run java application without using IDE?

Tags: java, command-line

I have a java application where main class is dependent with some other classes. I can run the application using an IDE well. But when I want to run the application from command line by locating to the main class's class file using `java mainClass`, it gives me the following error [the main class name is `mainClass`]:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mainClass(wrong name: mainfolder/mainClass)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Can anybody suggest me how can I run my application without using any IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uou need to indicate the fully qualified name. For example if `MainClass` is under package com.example, you should execute `java com.example.MainClass`

You can check more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

From documentation:

> By default, the first non-option argument is the name of the class to
>   be invoked. A fully-qualified class name should be used. If the -jar
>   option is specified, the first non-option argume nt is the name of a
>   JAR archive containing class and resource f iles for the application,
>   with the startup class indicated by the Main-Class manifest header.
>   The Java runtime searches for the startup class, and other classes
>   used, in three sets of locations: the bootstrap class path, the
>   installed extensions, and the user class path.

Comment: hey thanks! got the output after executing the java command with package.classname from outside the package folder!

Answer (score 0):

Try `mainfolder.mainclass` instead of `mainfolder/Mainclass`. Also, the mainfolder is the package.

Make sure you put all needed jars in the classpath with `-cp`.

Comment: Tried but got this:- "Error: Could not find or load main class mainfolder.mainClass"

Comment: hey thanks! got the output after executing the java command with package.classname from outside the package folder!

Answer (score 0):

With or without IDEs, java application can always start by

```
java -cp classpath EntryClass
```

If you run the application with IDEs, the IDE you using prepares the classpath for you. If you run without the IDEs, you should prepare the whole classpath yourself.

The EntryClass is also found through the classpath.

Please refer to [java - the Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you are runngin your java program from /home/flyleaf/app/

This would be the command you need:

```
javac -classpath /home/flyleaf/app/jar1.jar:/home/flyleaf/app/jar1.jar:/home/flyleaf/app/ com/app/your/mail/class/Main.java
```

You need to add to the classpath the jar files you need and the path where you got your program

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Got the output after executing the java command over the `main class's class file` with `package.classname` from outside the folder that contains the class files!

Besides the jar file is also working after locating the jar file and by executing this command `java -jar jarname.jar`!

Thanks everybody!